# How to create a new variable to store in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, double

I want to store a value in an ArrayList but how I can do it?

This is my code:

```
public class JavaTutorials{

    static double cor = 3.90000231;

    static double result = 0;

    static ArrayList<Double> chilist = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<Integer> ilist = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
        int j;
        for(j = 0; j <= 999999999; j++){
            result = result * cor + j;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Since `result` starts at `0`, and `0` times anything is `0`, you'll always get `0`. Also, the result of a computation at runtime is **not** a constant.

Comment: Ok but how I can to create automatically a new value to store in the ArrayList?

Comment: Did you try `chilist.add(result);` inside the loop?

Comment: But result is repeatable in the ArrayList?

Comment: What do you mean "repeatable"? You are calculating *a new value* and you want to *store in the ArrayList*.

Comment: I want to store multiple result value in the ArrayList.

Comment: Ok @cricket_007 I've solved, Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, the answer is exactly what I was asking if you had done.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch `result` is not always 0. The second loop will do `result = 0 + 1`.

Comment: Side note: you want to familiarize yourself with the javadoc material that is coming with most of the "built in" classes. Pretty much everything you will ever need to know is already written down there; typically in a straight-forward easy-to-digest form. So asking questions here is fine; but you might want to practice to do more prior research on your side first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
    int j;
    for(j = 0; j <= 999999999; j++){
        result = result * cor + j;
        chilist.add(result)
    }
}
```

something like this?